# How to read from file (from one string to another -multiple lines) in Python ver 3.5.2

Tags: python, file, user-interface, tkinter

I'm creating an application in Python (ver 3.5.2) with Tkinter and I'm having trouble with the following.

I want to read data from the file (from one string to another string - multiple lines). The "starting" string is users choice, and the end string is determined and that is '='.

What I've done so far is:

```
#click on button writes data from file:

    open = Button(self, text="Open", command = self.openTXT, width=20).grid(row=5, column=3, pady=5, padx = 10, sticky=W)

#user enters the starting string in file

        self.entry = Entry(self, width=30).grid(sticky = W, pady=7, padx=5, column=4, row=2)

#i want to display data from file in this Text field

self.text = Text(self).grid(column=4, row=4,pady=8, padx=5, columnspan=2, rowspan=6,sticky=E+W+S+N)

#this function finds the starting string and writes down line in which getInfo is found. How do I add the end string (the end string in my case is '=') and read multiple lines and not just one, like it is right now 
 def openTXT(self):
        getInfo = self.entry.get()
        f = open('mojDnevnik.txt', encoding='utf-8')
        for line in f.readlines():
            if getInfo in line:
                self.text.insert(1.0, line)
```

Example:

Users entry: "Sat"

File mojDnevnik.txt:

```
Friday Nov 18 2016

Testing

==========================================

Sat Nov 19 2016

Testing reading from file

==========================================
```

The output should be:

```
Sat Nov 19 2016

Testing reading from file
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I don't see a question. What part of the solution do you need help with?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a *flag* to signal when to capture the data -

```
def openTXT(self):
    getInfo = self.entry.get()
    f = open('mojDnevnik.txt', encoding='utf-8')
    flag = False
    for line in f.readlines():
        if getInfo in line:
            self.text.insert(1.0, line)
            flag = True
        elif flag and not line.startswith('='):
            self.text.insert(1.0, line)
        elif line.startswith('='):
            flag = False
```

---

Of course you may want to use a different name than `flag` so the code *makes sense* when you read it.

Comment: Thank you very much. It solved my problem. I also changed `self.text.insert(1.0, line)` to `self.text.insert(END, line)` so that it was organized exactly the same as it was in file.